# newline causes SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, newline

An ipad application sends this json to me and I read it by request.POST.get and then pars it by **ast.literal_eval**

```
u'[\n {\n "type" : 2,\n "dateCreated" : "Wed, 24 Apr 2013 17:20:50 0100",\n "dateStart" : "Wed, 24 Apr 2013 18:00:00 0100",\n "appointmentId" : 0,\n "withP" : [\n\n ],\n "seenTime" : null,\n "ofCWithId" : 2,\n "ofClientWithId" : 68,\n "dateEnd" : "Wed, 24 Apr 2013 19:00:00 0100",\n "comments" : "Test test test\n.\n( ) \'\' test \'\' \' test \'\n",\n "inLocation" : null,\n ...bla bla bla...]'
```

I get this error:

```
    'comments' : 'Test test test
                               ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I can understand that newline character is the problem but I don't know how to solve it. I'm using django 1.4.2 python 2.7.3

I really appreciate your help

Comment: And how is this text generated? The only way to solve this problem is to remove the newline characters from inside the quoted strings, but that basically requires you to write a parser from scratch.

Comment: Also your last word doesn't come quoted so that's gonna throw you a SyntaxError as well.

Comment: an ipad application sends this json to me and I read it by request.POST.get and then pars it by ast.literal_eval. As error message shows newline after Test test test causes the problem.

Comment: Since this is supposed to be JSON, why aren't you using the `json` library to parse it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I changed it to json.loads and it solved the problem, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add \'\'\' at the beginning of the string and at the end.

Like this:

```
u'\'\'\'[\n ... bla bla bla...]\'\'\''
```

Answer (score -1):

You **shouldn't** use *ast.literal_eval* to read JSON. For reading JSON there is a separate [module called `json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#module-json).

*Load JSON data using it:*

```
import json
data = """{"type":null,"dateCreated":"Wed, 24 Apr 2013 17:20:50 0100"}"""
json_data = json.loads(data)
```

*ast.literal_eval* was made to evaluate Python code that is represented as a string. It wasn't designed to work with JSON data.
`null` in JSON is `None` in Python Dictionary, as an example of a difference.

Another reason you get an error is because *JSON* you try to parse *is invalid*. It looks like there's a server side problem or there is a problem with the way you get your JSON data from the server.

Newline symbols (`\n`) should be escaped within a string. Also, `'` shouldn't be escaped, according to [JSON specs](http://www.json.org/). Alternatively, you can use `strict=False` argument with `json.loads` to allow control characters inside strings.

Valid JSON from your example would look like this:

```
{
    "type": 2,
    "dateCreated": "Wed, 24 Apr 2013 17:20:50 0100",
    "dateStart": "Wed, 24 Apr 2013 18:00:00 0100",
    "appointmentId": 0,
    "withP": ["\\n\\n"],
    "seenTime": null,
    "ofCWithId": 2,
    "ofClientWithId": 68,
    "dateEnd": "Wed, 24 Apr 2013 19:00:00 0100",
    "comments": "Test test test\\n.\\n( ) '' test '' ' test '\\n",
    "inLocation": null
}
```

Comment: This happens to me with json.loads also